# Form gets submitted if provide any value from form field Using PHP

Tags: php

When i provide value in any one field of form and click on ragister it gets submitted but should not submit till the all field get filled what i am doing wrong please let me know, as I have taken pre tag at the top where i can see all the values that i'm getting when i click on ragister.

```
<?php

$error_array = array();
$fname = $lname = $email = $dob = $Mchecked = $Fchecked = $hobbies ="";

if(isset($_GET["sbt_save"]))
{   
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_GET); echo "</pre>";
    if($_GET['fname']=="")
    {           
        $err ="Please Enter your first name"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $fname = test_input($_GET['fname']);
    }

    if($_GET['lname']=="")
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your last name"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $lname = test_input($_GET["lname"]);
    }

    if($_GET['email']=="")
    {       
        $err ="Please Enter your email"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $email = test_input($_GET["email"]);
    }

    if($_GET['dob']=="")
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your date of birth"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $dob = test_input($_GET["dob"]);
    }

    if(!isset($_GET["gender"]))
    {
        $err ="Please select gender"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $gender = $_GET["gender"];
        if ($gender == "Male")
        {
            $Mchecked = "checked";
        }
        else if ($gender == "Female")
        {
            $Fchecked = "checked";
        }
    }

    if(!isset($_GET['hobbies']))
    {
        $err ="Please Enter your hobbies"."<br>";
        array_push($error_array,$err);
    }
    else
    {
        $hobbies = test_input($_GET['hobbies']);
    }
}

function test_input($data)
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ragistration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ragistration_form.css">
<!--
<script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(event)
{    
    $(".sbt_button").click(function(event)
    {        
        var error_arr = [];             
        var email_value = $("#email").val();                    
        var position_of_at  = email_value.indexOf('@');         
        var position_of_dot = email_value.lastIndexOf('.');



        if($("#fname").val() == null || $("#fname").val() == "")
        {
             var err = "First Name";
             error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#lname").val() == null || $("#lname").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Last Name ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }
        if(position_of_at == -1 || position_of_dot == -1 || (position_of_at + 2) >= position_of_dot )
        {
            var err = "Email ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if($("#dob").val() == null || $("#dob").val() == "")
        {
            var err = "Date of Birth ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='radio']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Gender ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }

        if(!$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked"))
        {
            var err = "Hobbies ";
            error_arr.push(err);
        }


        if(error_arr.length !=0)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            alert(error_arr);   
        }           
    });
});

</script>
-->
</head>
<body>
<form class="form" name="myForm" action="" method="GET">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <p class="heading">Ragistration Form</p>
    </tr>
    <?php
if($error_array !="")
{   
    foreach($error_array as $value)
    {       
        echo "<tr style='color:red;'><td> ". $value. "</td></tr>";                  
    }
}

?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">First Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="inputfield_Name"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Last Name :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="inputfield_Name"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Email :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="inputfield_Name"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Date of Birth :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"  class="inputfield_Name"   /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Gender :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"class="inputfield_Name" <?php echo $Mchecked;?>   />
        Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php echo $Fchecked;?>    />
        Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">About Yourself :</td>
      <td><textarea name="abt" class="inputfield_Name"$></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="field_Name">Hobbies :<b style="color:red">*</b></td>
      <td><input name="hobbies" value="Cricket"  type="checkbox" id="hobbies"  class="inputfield_Name"    />
        Cricket
        <input name="hobbies" value="Singing"   type="checkbox"   />
        Singing
        <input name="hobbies" value="Travling"   type="checkbox"  />
        Travling</td>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="hobbies"  value="Writing"  type="checkbox"  class="inputfield_Name"  />
        Writing
        <input name="hobbies"  value="Teaching"  type="checkbox"   />
        Teaching
        <input name="hobbies"  value="Driving"  type="checkbox"   />
        Driving </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Ragister" name="sbt_save"  class="sbt_button"/></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it currently stands, the form will submit though the submission may be invalid. It's important to recognize that PHP is server-side so this validation will occur after submission. JavaScript is client-side and can be used to immediately validate and to prevent form submission if any field is invalid. I see that you have some JavaScript but it's commented out. Is something wrong with that portion of code?

Comment: @War10ck no its working i just commented to check whether php's validation is working or not that's it

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, its working fine. See the below screenshot.

[image]
If you want to validate your form before submit then use the commented javascript/client-side validation and if you want to validate it afterwards then use your php/server-side validation.

Let me know if you are facing any other problem.